# A general response for a missing header value

Tags: .net, webapi

I am writing a WebAPI in .NET6.

All requests (or at least all POST/PUT/DELETE requests) to my API should include a custom header value. Can I make a general response (which I assume should be BadRequest) with an error message if this is missing without having to repeat the logic in all controller methods?

I have seen IAsyncActionFilter as a potential way of doing this but there it seems only to be possible to set a result type but not to include an error message.

What would be the "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Are you re-inventing Authentication/Authorization here? If so, you should be looking at existing middleware/headers/responses

Comment: Not trying to re-invent anything - just trying to learn how this should be done.